# git push origin <branchName> not actually doing anything

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

When I push my local branch to origin, I don't see it on github.com, and therefore can't make a PR to merge with master. No errors, and when I try to push again it says `Everything is up-to-date`

Any idea what's going on..?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `origin` is actually GitHub? What does `git remote show origin` give you?

Comment: please show what error you are getting. its impossible for us to help if you show nothing here!

Comment: origin is definitely on github as i've pushed about ten trillion branches (slight exaggeration) before and everything worked fine. `remote show origin` gives the github repo for both push and pull. @uDaY there is literally no error to show. seemingly, everything is working

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset wait a second, just saw this: `Local refs configured for 'git push': <branchName> pushes to <branchName> (up to date)` <- both `<branchNams>`s are the same. is this the issue..? i've never encountered this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going to https://status.github.com/, you'll see that they currently experience database problems and latency delays. So, I would suggest that you wait until they fix the problem.

Updated: they report that everything has been fixed now:https://status.github.com/messages